# Struts to spring migration tool with custom tags

Tags: spring, struts-1

We have very large struts 1.x apllication with custom tags. We want to migrate it to spring 3.x.

> Are there any best tools to automate this process or do we have to do it manually?

Comment: You'll need to do it manually.

Comment: Are there any tools which can automate at least some part of it?